# Page reload ask to submit data over and over again

Tags: php, wordpress, reload

I have the following ***code** below, every time I refresh the page it asks me to send the form again. How do I avoid that, I don't want to resend a form on a page refresh. Thanks in advance.

***CODE**

```
<?php function make_user_feedback_form() {
    global $wpdb;
    global $current_user;


        $ufUserID = $current_user->ID;

        if ( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) && $_POST['action'] == 'updateFeedback' ) {
            $ufDataUpdate = $wpdb->insert( 'wp_user_feedback', array( 'date' => current_time('mysql'), 'responses' => $_POST["test"]) );
        }
        }?>
    <div id="form">
    <ol>
        <form method="post">
            <li><label for="test">Question 01</label><input type="text" id="datepicker" name="test" value="" /></li> <!-- the (name="test") value is what the ('responses' => $_POST["test"]) value is talking too -->

            <li><input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" class="submit button" value="Send feedback" /></li>
            <?php wp_nonce_field( 'updateFeedback' ); ?>
            <input name="action" type="hidden" id="action" value="updateFeedback" />
        </form>
    </ol>
    </div>
    <?php 


add_action('the_content','make_user_feedback_form');
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have processed the form data and stored it in the database or worked with it in some way, reload the same page using:

```
header("location: thispage.php");
```

Doing this will destroy the POST data and allow the page to be refreshed without displaying the resubmit alert.

Comment: I tried it right after the add_action but I get this error Cannot modify header information - headers already sent

Comment: You must make sure that nothing has been sent to the browser before sending the header. Ideally, at the top of your page you should check to see if the form has been submitted. If so, then save the data and send the header. After that you can display the page content.